# How is the node revision ID getting updated?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a question related to `_node_save_revision` function in drupal 7. I just want to know how I can get the new revision ID after saving a revision using this function

It is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/_node_save_revision/7.x).

> The resulting revision ID is available afterward in `$node->vid`.

But how does this happen? Where is the new revision ID assigned to the node object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drupal_write_record` handles that.

`vid` is the primary key on the `node_revision` table, as declared in [`node_schema`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.install/function/node_schema/7.x), and `drupal_write_record` knows that because it introspects the schema when writing the record.

From there it just takes the ID returned from the database query, and populates the correct property on the object that was passed in. In this case, that's the `vid` property on the node object.

Comment: Could you please tell me where exactly it is happening in `drupal_write_record`.( https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7.x).

Comment: Like exactly which lines? `$object->$serial = $fields[$serial];` and `$object->$serial = $query_return;`